# Avoid duplicate activity or fragment due to multi-touch or double tapping?

Tags: android, android-fragments, multi-touch, onclicklistener

In my app I have many view that will either launch an activity or add a fragment to the stack. In both cases I want to avoid that double tapping the view or tapping two of the same views (like two items in a list) can start the same activity or fragment multiple times.

This question has already been asked multiple times and the only solutions are to disable the whole activity (by any way) or disable all the clickable views when a view is clicked. This works for double tapping but not for multi-touch tapping of two views at the same time.

Futhermore, I wish to find a solution that is more generic. I have lots of clickable views, lots of activities and lots of fragments.

Comment: Would a `boolean` flag help? Place all `startActivity(i)` in an `if-block`: `if (canStart) { canStart = false; startActivity(i); }`. `canStart` is `true` by default.

Comment: @user2558882 This works well, but only for activities. What could I do for fragments?

Comment: Also this does not work for startActivityForResult because onResume doesn't get called and onActivityResult doesn't get called either because child activities don't call super method to avoid conflicts in requestCodes.

Comment: Actually, this works well in a lot of situations. An example, other than when starting an activity: It prevents the app from crashing due to `BadTokenException` when showing a `PopupWindow` on orientation change.

Comment: For fragments: create a helper method: `preventMultipleFragments(FragmentManager myFragmentManager, Fragment myFragment, String fTag)`. Wait for current transaction to finish using: `myFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()`. Then check `if(myFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fTag) == null)`. If it is, add `myFragment`. Make some changes to suit your needs.

Comment: `Also this does not work for startActivityForResult because onResume doesn't get called and onActivityResult doesn't get called either because child activities don't call super method to avoid conflicts in requestCodes.` I am not sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding this to our parent Activity class:

```
private Intent mActivityStarted = null;

[...]

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    if (mActivityStarted == null || mActivityStarted == intent) {
        mActivityStarted = intent;
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    if (mActivityStarted == null || mActivityStarted == intent) {
        mActivityStarted = intent;
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mActivityStarted = null;
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I also added this in our parent Fragment class and it shares the same mActivityStarted by using ((*OurParentActivityClass*) getActivity()).*getterForMActivityStarted*()

For launching fragments only once, I also made it change the same mActivityStarted.